# Get data from DataGridView to Chart

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts, dataset

I need to get data from a single DataGridView into 3 distinct Charts, each column to a chart.
This is the first time I'm working with charts, so I've researched a bit about them but couldn't find anything that could help me with this specific problem.

Here follows a screenshot of what my DataGridView and my Charts are like, with their respective legends:

[image: DataGridView and Charts]

What I need is (at least in theory) a very simple thing. In the "SANITY" chart I need to get the value located at `Table[0, 0]` into something like `sanityChart.Series[0]` as its 'Y' value, and so on. Same thing for "UNIT" and "ISSUES DB".
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do learn about Chart! It can show one or more Series or DataPoints in one or more ChartAreas. You can add a Datapoint to a Series like this: Series.AddXY(xval, yval): chart1.Series[0]Points.AddXY[3,3]; Chose a ChartType! The base datatype for the x- and y-values is double.

Comment: @TaW thanks mate, the `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 3);` already gave me a tip on what to do.

Comment: Yes. I note that you have three Series. Each can have many dataPoints. So maybe you only need one chart..? If you have columns you can give each a separate color, too..

Comment: @TaW Yeah that would work as well. Just post that `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 3);` as an answer to this question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way you asked the question and the image you have shown I believe that you want something like this:

[image]

I use only one `Chart` and I have added one `Series` for each of your `Columns`.

After setting up the chart I have added one data point for each row in the table to each of the series/columns..:

```
// setting up the datagridview
Table.Rows.Clear();
Table.Columns.Clear();
Table.Columns.Add("state", "");
Table.Columns.Add("sanity", "SANITY");
Table.Columns.Add("unit", "UNIT");
Table.Columns.Add("issuesDb", "ISSUES DB");
// filling in some data
Table.Rows.Add("ALL PASSED", 86, 21, 2);
Table.Rows.Add("FAILED", 7, 0, 1);
Table.Rows.Add("Cancelled", 0, 0, 0);

// Now we can set up the Chart:
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>{Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Black};

chart1.Series.Clear();

for (int i = 0 ; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Series S = chart1.Series.Add(Table[0, i].Value.ToString());
    S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    S.Color = colors[i];
}

// and fill in all the values from the dgv to the chart:
for (int i = 0 ; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1 ; j < Table.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
      int p = chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(Table.Columns[j].HeaderText, Table[j, i].Value);
   }
}
```

Note that I have chosen to add the `DataPoints` with the `AddXY` overload and also decided that I want to make my life a little easier by adding the `X-Values` as `strings`. Internally they are still transformed to `doubles` and will all have a value of `0`! Not a problem for us here, but it is important to understand that we didn't use valid numbers and therefore can't treat them as numbers! The advantage is that the axis labels are being set to the column headers without any further work..